# Header menu and Footer disappeared after migrating website to new server

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Just migrated a website to a new server, same domain name, and now the header including the menu and footer have disappeared.

I'm not a programmer, so please let me know if the information provided is not sufficient to understand what's going on and I will get you whatever else you need.

The first image shows the site prior to the migration and the second, after the migration with the header gone...

[image]

[image]

From my limited understanding, looking at the index.html source, it seems this is the code that loads the menu...

```
<!--jQuery-->
<script src="/css/5grid/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/css/5grid/init.js?use=mobile,desktop,1000px&amp;mobileUI=0&amp;mobileUI.theme=none&amp;mobileUI.openerWidth=52"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.hsmenu.min.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-ie9.css" /><![endif]-->

<script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
         
         $(".hs-menubar").hsMenu(); 
         
         }); 
      </script>
</head>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to list any errors in your console etc.  what kind of server was the site on before and what server is it on now? It’s possible that there is a JS error on your page but it’s hard to diagnose without more info.

Comment: Migrated from Apache to Litespeed.

Here is the error on the console:

[link](https://ibb.co/YDbpfBq)

Comment: While there’s no way to tell for sure if this is the problem for your disappearing header/footer, it is one problem.  If you note the url you will see the term ‘undefined’, meaning that there is a variable in your js that is does not contain a value that is required and your get request is failing.  I would find out where that call is being made and why the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

AS it turns out, ssi (server-side includes) was not enabled in Nginx.

To enable it, I had to add the the folowing to /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite.com.conf, server block:

`ssi on;`